# backpack for laravel trying to implement permissions, roles

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

i've installed permission manager for the backpack crud package,it lets me to implement permissions, roles, users, but there's no example where to put the code to validate a user satisfy the requirements.

for example : i added the code below inside function setup() in my equipment controller and it shows an error , should i use middleware in routes??

i recently created the middleware :

```
 class RoleMiddleware
 {
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission)
{      


     // dd($request->user()); 
     // if (!Auth::user()->hasRole($role)) { 

     //      Alert::add('error', 'You do not have necessary authorization to access to the page')->flash(); return redirect('home'); 
     // } 

    // dd($request->user());
     if (Auth::guest()) {

       return redirect(url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix').'/login'));
      }

     dd($request->user()->hasRole($role));  //si pregunta si tiene el rol de administrador
     if (!$request->user()->hasRole($role)) {

         Alert::info('You do not have necessary authorization to access to the page Role');
        // abort(403);
      }

    if (!$request->user()->can($permission))  // pregunta si tiene el permiso de back_end
    {

        Alert::error('You do not have necessary authorization to access to the page Permission');
        abort(403);
     }


    return $next($request);
}
```

}

my routes :

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','role:admin,access_backend']], function() {

CRUD::resource('equipos', 'EquiposCrudController');
CRUD::resource('regiones', 'RegionesCrudController');
CRUD::resource('parametros', 'ParametrosCrudController');
CRUD::resource('estaciones', 'EstacionesCrudController'); 
}
```

What if i have an user Editor that has 1 Role "Edit" and  Permission "back_end" and "edit" ,
  having the middleware setup like that only accepts my Editor user only if it comply with admin role. right?? should i add to my editor user the role admin as well? the problem being that role admin has permission to everything.

i'm intended to implement the code below dynamically on each controller,instead of asking for every role. any alternatives?

```
class EquiposCrudController extends CrudController
{

 public function setup() {

   if($user->hasRole('editor')){

        $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete']);
    }

   if($user->hasRole('usuario')){

      $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete','update']);
   }
```

Comment: Doing it in setup looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes middleware is a good choice for checking a user's authentication 
 and authorization levels. You can easily interrogate the request object and redirect accordingly. The actual authentication (logging in / out) of the software should be handled by a controller.

Look into Laravel's Gates and Policies as well, they provide a fine tuned level of access for individual users, such as you mentioned where a User has specific permissions.

This is an excellent place to get started with all this:

https://josephsilber.com/index.php/posts/2016/08/03/authorization-improvements-in-laravel-5-3

Comment: thanks, i'm looking into laravel's Gates and Policies ,

Comment: at the moment being, my head is spinning at the thought of trying to make role checks dynamically EquiposCrudController extends CrudController
{
    
     public function setup() {

       if($user->hasRole('editor')){
       
            $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete']);
        }
       
       if($user->hasRole('usuario')){

          $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete','update']);
       }

Comment: If you're doing generic role check, create a middleware for each for and apply it to your routes accordingly. If you're using resource routes and controllers, you can use automatically authorize using authorizeResource(Model::class) in the controller to make things easier.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
$user = Auth::user();

if($user->hasRole('editor')){
    $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete']);
}

if($user->hasRole('usuario')){
  $this->crud->denyAccess(['create','delete','update']);
}
```